# time machine and paradox problem

Tags: alternate-history, history

After doing more research on the earlier question.  I have rewritten my question in order to change the framing so that it is not about characters but more about my factions and their use of the time machine.

The Context:

Imagine every current man-made problem in the world got worse.  Dystopia arrives.   Then a time travel device is invented.  A faction  of anti-technologists think the time machine might be a way of impeding the progress of human kind and resetting it to a simpler time with less problems.  At this future point in human history, when much of the environment of the Earth has been destroyed by technology, they believe this is the only way to solve the humankind's issues.

The Problem:
The anti-technologists have determined a path through time where they will show up and disrupt various technological inventions from progressing. The problem is one of a paradox of course, the time machine they are travelling in itself is dependent on these technologies.  I am not sure how the paradox can be evaded.

How could I deal with it in order for my premise to continue?

Comment: You are asking us to write your story for you. This is not what we do here.

Comment: if i wanted to save the world by undoing inventions, i'd make sure the world never heard of the GargleBlorp-Device, and the alchemical refinement of Unobtanium from old horseshoes.

Comment: VTC as fundamentally opinion-based: as @L.Dutch said, you are asking for a story, not for a world. (And why on Earth would they target technological achievements as such instead of choosing the very much easier path of targeting events which set up the conditions which led to the technological inventions being possible in the first place? For example kill [Miltiades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miltiades) and make sure the Persians win at [Marathon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miltiades)? Greece becomes part of the Persian Empire: there is no western civilization; problem solved.)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, what do you mean you never discovered slood?

Comment: The focus is on the history of crucial inventions, and there is a problem with having an Unobtanium device as the starting point.  I'll agree that it is a problem, but not much different from any time travel or alternative history narrative.

Comment: @AlexP, in this case even the suggestion that you would start at the beginning of western civilization would be helpful for my question.

Comment: When you say the beginning of western civilisation, which precise beginning are you referring to? The establishment of NATO, the colonisation of the Americas, the enlightenment, the building of Rome, the establishment of Athens as a civilisation-hub, the westward migration of proto-Indo-Europeans across Eurasia to the west? Your question at present is unclear and seems to be asking for us to write your story for you.

Comment: The easiest answer to this question is to blow up the meteor that wiped out the dinosaur or hunt our ancestral species to extinction. Humanity is gone, crab rave. On a serious note now: to stop the plane from existing at the time it did, you'd need to stop both Santos Dumont in Brazil and the Wright Brothers in the USA and then destroy their entire research, for stopping only one wouldn't keep the plane from appearing. You'd then need to go to any would be new inventor of the plane in the new timeline for there to be no planes. You can't ensure humans don't invents if humans still exist.

Comment: @A Rogue Ant.  Yes, it is tricky because it needs to be more singular events not phases.  @ProjectApex,   true.

Comment: Please be aware that we advise you not accept answers for the first 24-48 hours as it discourages answers from our international community. Also, you can only @ a single person per comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this list can't be exhaustive or deterministic. The development of technology is not one-innovation-followed-by-another-innovation-by-irreplaceable-people. Most innovation is going on concurrently in many areas, so removing one, or a hundred, people wouldn't stop the innovation. That means you're asking us to develop a *short list* of such innovations - and that's the basis of a plot, which is off-topic.

Comment: `and there is a problem with having an Unobtanium device as the starting point` - prevent mankind from discovering advanced metallurgy, and - swoosh - basic _iron_ turns into unobtanium.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann, Right, these unibombers would be the first to un-invent the time machine.

Comment: May I recommend looking at common time travel tropes?  There are *dozens* of ways for time travel to work in the corpus of all science fiction.  Some of them directly solve paradoxes like this.  Others suggest ways to phrase things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd play whack-a-mole. Go back and prevent the known origination of an idea, but while you are there, figure out what inspired it, and then try to stop THAT.

Although many inventions are the result of accumulating knowledge passing some tipping point, not all of them are. Einstein invented Relativity out of whole cloth. Perhaps he would not have, if he'd been given a different job, a lucrative job instead of going to school for physics. Or, he went to learn to **teach** physics, not become a physicist. What if he'd been given a job teaching something besides physics?

All ideas begin in one head, somewhere. Destroy that head, or divert that head onto a different path, and you change the future. That is the whole point of time travel, isn't it?

Comment: (1) There is a difference between a discovery and an invention. (2) Einsteinian relativity is one kind of relativity. Galilean relativity is another, and that kind of relativity had been known for three centuries. (3) If it wasn't Einstein it would have been somebody else. It had become painfully obvious that Galilean relativity did not work for electromagnetism, and many physicists were looking for solutions. [Hendrik Lorentz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrik_Lorentz) and [Henri Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincaré) come to mind.

Comment: Einstein did not invent relativity out of while cloth. His theories explained results from a series of experiments which tried to measure the speed of the aether (the predecessor theory to relativity) which instead found that the speed of light must be constant. Michelson–Morley is the most famous one, but there are others.

Comment: @10ebbor10 Yes, Einstein was thinking about that, but a constant speed of light is not "Special Relativity" or "General Relativity". Einstein DID invent those out ofwhole cloth, he was the only person on Earth we know of that figured out the implications of a constant speed of light, the contraction of time and increase of matter; Einstein invented the Space-Time Continuum, single-handed.

Comment: @AlexP You don't know it would be "somebody else", nobody else on earth was talking about a Space-Time Continuum, nobody else on Earth proved E=MC^2, or was talking about time dilation with speed or mass increase with speed. If it hadn't been Einstein, no telling how long it would have taken. Further, Relativity is fundamentally at odds with Quantum Physics, and nearly all physicists think Relativity is at fault. They cannot be reconciled, and at quantum distances Relativity makes no sense. If Quantum was invented first, General Relativity may well be dismissed as an obvious non-starter.

Comment: @Amadeus: Nobody? So Hendrik Lorentz is a fictional character? The basic coordinate transformations in Einsteinian relativity are to this day called [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation). And the stuff which is in contradiction with QM is Einstein's [general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity), which is fundamentally a theory of gravitation. Nobody has anything against [special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity), which is the actual description of coordinate transformation.

Comment: @AlexP yes, they are called Lorentz transformations, but they did not apply to **time** or **mass**, they were about the Doppler Effect. That's like saying because Einstein used a square root then he wasn't original. The Lorentz transformation did not even make sense for the audio-wave application it was designed for. And what Einstein did was **derive** the Lorentz transformation from the notion that the speed of light was constant to all observers. See "On the Origin of the Lorentz Transformation" at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5309.pdf

Comment: @Amadeus: (1) Arxiv is not a good source of information about history. (2) The Lorenz transformations absolutely apply to time. (3) They were derived *explicitly* in order to find a way to account for the invariance of Maxwell's equations in moving frames. (4) There were quite a few physicists who understood the time dilation implications, starting with [Joseph Larmor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Larmor). (5) Yes, Einstein did assemble everything in a nice package. (6) E.g., [Henri_Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Poincaré) immediately recognized Einstein's contributions.